# AFNetworking Post Form-Data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, afnetworking

I am trying to do a simple POST request with Form-Data to an api but I always get a status 401 in return.

I can easily make the call outside of xcode (in Postman for instance) with success, all I do is POST to the url with key-value pairs of type Form-Data but in xcode it always fails.

Here is my AFHTTPClient:

```
@implementation UnpaktAPIClient

+ (id)sharedInstance {
    static UnpaktAPIClient *__sharedInstance;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        __sharedInstance = [[UnpaktAPIClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UnpaktAPIBaseURLString]];
    });
    return __sharedInstance;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (self) {
        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self setParameterEncoding:AFFormURLParameterEncoding];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSDictionary *)login:(NSDictionary *)credentials {

    [[UnpaktAPIClient sharedInstance] postPath:@"/api/v1/users/login"
                                    parameters:credentials
                                        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
                                            NSLog(@"success");
                                        }
                                        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
                                            NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                        }];

    return nil;
}
```

I've also attempted creating a request with a requestOperation:

```
- (NSDictionary *)login:(NSDictionary *)credentials {

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[UnpaktAPIClient sharedInstance] requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/api/v1/users/login" parameters:credentials];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                                        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id json) {
                                                                                            NSLog(@"success");
                                                                                        }
                                                                                        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id json){
                                                                                            NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                                                        }];
    [operation start];

    return nil;
}
```

But I get the exact same error all the time: `Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in (200-299), got 401"`. I'm expecting JSON feedback, you can see the success condition in the attached picture. I suspect it's something very simple but I'm pulling my hair out trying to find it, I'm quite new to networking. Any help would be awesome, thanks.[image: Postman Success]

**UPDATE**

Since the Postman request has blank params and headers, I figured I needed to get to the form body. Changing the request to:

```
- (NSDictionary *)login:(NSDictionary *)credentials {

    NSURLRequest *request = [self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                            path:@"/api/v1/users/login"
                                                      parameters:nil
                                       constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

                                       }];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                                        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id json) {
                                                                                            NSLog(@"success");
                                                                                        }
                                                                                        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id json) {
                                                                                            NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                                                        }];
    [operation start];
    return nil;
}
```

Now gives me a 404 error, which is what I would expect without a valid email and password, I just need to figure out how to add one to the body of the form, anything I try to add gives me the "request body stream exhausted" error.

Comment: have you added protocol to your url, example http:// ?

Comment: Yes, the error URL that gets reported is the correct one I should be authenticating against.

Comment: It may be problem with basic http authentication. For basic authentication, this works for me: NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]]; //tmpBase 64 is base64 of credentials in format username:password NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@",tmpBase64]; [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

Comment: @IvanAlek Thanks, you helped point in the right direction. See my update, I think if I can just get the key/value pairs loaded correctly I'll be good to go.

Comment: Function to create a base64 string for the password can be found here: http://www.calebmadrigal.com/string-to-base64-string-in-objective-c/ This solution works for me with `multipartFormRequestWithMethod` of `AFNetworking`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it, turns out it's a little verbose to add key/value pairs to form-data but I accomplished it like so:

```
NSMutableData *email = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSMutableData *password = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[email appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"paul+100@test.com"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[password appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"qwerty"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[formData appendPartWithFormData:email name:@"email"];
[formData appendPartWithFormData:password name:@"password"];
```